# Django Queryset filter for arguments in a list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a list of names:

```
name_list = ['John', 'Bill', 'Charlie']
```

I would like to filter for results where the name field matches any of these names.  How can I implement this in queryset?  The code I am using is:

```
Special_group = People.objects.filter(name=name_list(?))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for this query.

```
Special_group = People.objects.filter(name__in=name_list)
```

This type of query is called a [`field_lookup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) in Django. There are a lot of other operations such as `iexact`, `contains`, `lte`, `gte` and a lot more.